# The set of accumulation points of a sequence is compact

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence is $\mathbb R$. Suppose that $(x_n)$ is bounded and $\lim_{n}(x_{n + 1} - x_n) = 0$. Prove that:

$B := \{x; x \in \bar {(x_n)}\}$ is compact.

In addition, prove that: $B = [inf(B), sup(B)]$.

I have no idea how to do this. Does any one know how to prove it? thanks..

Comment: Show that $B$ is bounded (almost immediate) and closed. You can do the latter directly, or show that the complement is open.

Comment: A closed bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $B$ is closed and bounded.

- Bounded is easy, since the sequence itself is bounded, say in $[m,M]$ and $B\subseteq [m,M]$ (can you see why?).
- Closed: take any converging sequence $(a_n)_n$ in $B$, and show its limit is also in $B$. You can do that by contradiction, assuming $(a_n)_n$ has two adherence values $\alpha < \alpha^\prime$; to get the contradiction, you'll need to use the fact that $x_n-x_{n+1} \to 0$.

Comment: I added something. Check it please.

Comment: @goldenratio: The assertion that you added is false: consider the sequence $x_n=\frac1n$, for which $B=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$, while $[\inf B,\sup B]=[0,1]$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I'm not certain to understand your example -- isn't $B$ equal to $\{0\}$ in your case? (the set of accumulation points of a convergence sequence only contains its limit.)

Comment: @Clement: Your question defines $B$ as the closure of the set of points of the sequence, not as the set of accumulation points. But the statement is false for the set of accumulation points as well, as may be seen by setting $x_n=(-1)^n+\frac1n$. The resulting sequence has$1$ and $-1$ as accumulation points, not $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Indeed -- sorry.